# ClassCastException: android.os.Handler$MessengerImpl cannot be cast to My

Tags: android, android-service, classcastexception, android-handler, android-binder

I have declared an `handler` in my `service`:

```
final Messenger messenger = new Messenger(new MusicAPIControlHandler());

public class MusicPlayerBinder extends Binder {
    public MusicPlayerService getService() {
        return MusicPlayerService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return messenger.getBinder();
}

public class MusicAPIControlHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        //
    }
}
```

In my class which implements the `ServiceConnection` and which binds the `service`, I do the following:

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
    handler = (MusicPlayerService.MusicAPIControlHandler) iBinder;

}
```

My problem is, I get the a `ClassCastException` when I try to cast the binder to my `handler`, which actually should be an instance of it because it´s set to the binder of the messenger.

Where am i going wrong?

**I have NOT declared my service as an process**

Comment: why dont you Log.d iBinder.getClass() ?

Comment: I´ve logged it. android.os.Handler$MessengerImpl

Comment: shouldnt you new
Messenger(iBinder) ?

Comment: Thats what I did now and it actually works. Thank you